# proc tabulate - producing count instead of sum

Tags: sas

A data source have the following fields

```
@0050 V1028       15.    /* Peso COM pÛs estratificaÁ„o */
@0187 V403311      $1.    /* Faixa do valor do rendimento hab. */
@0098 V3002A      $1.    /* A escola que ... frequenta È de */
```

V1028 is imported correctly into SAS as a Type: Numeric with Length: 8.

However, when I run the following code:

```
proc tabulate data=pnadc_012019;
  class V403311 V3002A;
  var V1028;
  table V403311, V3002A;
run;
```

the resulting table shows the count (N), not the sum of variable V1028.

[image]

How do I instruct SAS to calculate the sum of this variable within proc tabulate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your analysis variable to the table, or use the `freq` statement.

```
proc tabulate data=pnadc_012019;
  class V403311 V3002A;
  var V1028;
  table V403311, V3002A*V1028;
run;
```

OR;

```
proc tabulate data=pnadc_012019;
  class V403311 V3002A;
  var V1028;
  table V403311, V3002A;
  freq V1028;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you! The first suggestion worked, but the second didn't.

Comment: Good to hear. The second was a total shot in the dark and honestly not totally the best way to do it :)